# Matlab cell array to python list conversion

Tags: python, matlab, type-conversion

I have Matlab cell array of size `(1,260)`, but I am unable to convert it into a Python list. My code is as follow:

```
i=sio.loadmat('bispec.mat')
k=i['a']
```

After executing the code, I get these entities in the variable explorer.

[image: explorer variables]

I am trying to convert the Matlab cell array named `k` to the Python list by the following code.

```
val = np.asarray(k, dtype='float').tolist()
```

But I get the following error.

[image: Error]

Comment: Can you give the data you tried it on?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M_RE6ODmvj_xlO4cKwhMiPKILabS9d3B

Comment: Kindly show your full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in one of the images, you have tried:

`val = np.asarray(k, dtype='double').tolist()`.

There should not be inverted commas around `double`. You should be actually using:

`val = np.asarray(k, dtype=np.longdouble).tolist()`.

Adding further, one more reason for this error to occur is trying to use a string as an element in an array type of `double`. If you really want to have a NumPy array containing both strings and doubles, you could use the dtype `object`, which enables the array to hold arbitrary Python objects, as shown.

`val = np.asarray(k, dtype=object).tolist()`.

Comment: I have tried it but not working. The following error is generated:
val = np.asarray(k, dtype=double).tolist()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-31-3073a1f47c25>", line 1, in <module>
    val = np.asarray(k, dtype=double).tolist()

NameError: name 'double' is not defined

Comment: val = np.asarray(k, dtype=object).tolist()

It worked. Thanks